# iPhone App / Framework Linking

Tags: iphone

I am trying to compile an iPhone app and I am getting the errors below

`.objc_class_name_UILabel", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in

      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in libFBPlatform.a(FBDialog.o)
 .objc_class_name_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAKeyframeAnimation in libSCKit.a(CAAnimationAdditions.o)
 .objc_class_name_NSMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
 _OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLDocument", referenced from:
 .objc_class_name_UIActivityIndicatorView", referenced from:
 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCParserObject", referenced from:
 _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCImageLoadOperation", referenced from:
 _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCGroupTableViewCellBackgroundView", referenced from:
 .objc_class_name_NSMutableSet", referenced from:
 _objc_exception_try_enter", referenced from:
 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCNavigationBar", referenced from:`

I think this means that I have some Frameworks that are not linked but I dont know how to tell which frameworks are missing.  Is there an easy way to tell or is it pretty much just a manual process of googling an error, seeing which framework could have thrown that and adding then adding it.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you for each class which framework it is in. In your case, you would need `UIKit.framework` (UILabel), `QuartzCore.framework` (CAKeyframeAnimation), and `Foundation.framework` (NSMutableURLRequest). Since two of these 3 are included by default in any standard iOS project, yours seems pretty messed up.

Comment: Yea, it is pretty messed up.  Its a really old iPhone app, it was developed using 2.0 as the based SDK and now they want it upgraded, im considering just telling them its better to start over from scratch.

Comment: I added those libs by clicking target -> (General Tab) "+" -> Selecting the libs etc... and the build errors are the same.  I didn't expect them all to go away but since I added the libs I thought some would, am I missing a step somewhere?